# How does Visual Studio decide Nullable<T> is not a struct?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

```
Nullable<int> intNullable = null;//this is ok since `Nullable<T> where T : struct`
```

However `Nullable<Nullable<int>>` is NOT OK although `Nullable<int>` is a struct.

How is this possible?

Comment: public struct Nullable<T> where T : struct

Comment: Rather than abstract corners of the language... What **problem** led to you wanting a `Nullable<Nullable<T>>`? Give us that to solve instead.

Comment: Bear in mind that the compilers have specific support for nullables. Whilst the type system may say something is okay, it's fine for the compilers to get upset with it.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I did not encounter any specific problem besides not being able to place a struct where a struct is required.

Comment: @SeckinCelik A *non-nullable* struct is required, as per the error message you get when you try to do it.  You're providing a *nullable* struct, which doesn't meet that condition.

Comment: @SeckinCelik - you've misunderstood. I fully understand you tried to create a `Nullable<Nullable<T>>`. I wanted to understand what *led you to wanting to create such a thing in the first place*.

Answer (score 3):

There is special language support for `Nullable<T>`, in numerous ways, one of which is that `Nullable<Nullable<T>>` is not valid.  You could not create your own custom generic struct that could have any other struct *except itself* as the generic argument.  The generic constraint function of C# just isn't powerful enough to do it.

Also note that the error message does not say that `Nullable<int>` isn't a struct, it says that it must be a *non-nullable struct*.  `Nullable<int>` isn't a **non-nullable** struct.  It's a *nullable* struct.